# How to fit an image in a non-fixed height container?

Tags: css

I would like to fit an image in a non-fixed heigth container. This code is not working and I have no idea why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      /*height: 50vh;*/
      max-height: 50vh;
      background: #a00;
    }
    .wrapper img {
      max-height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/7395_saturn_gill_infrared.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You get the expected result when uncommenting the `height: 50vh;` but I don't want to fix the height.

Any idea?

**Update: Why would I want to do that?**

The real world example is a slider of images with pagination bullets that are below the slide (not overlaying them but really outside). In case a user is using a viewport with a height smaller than the default height of the slider, then I want the user to be able to see an entire slide AND the pagination bullets in the viewport.

Slides (images) are content, not styling elements. Therefore, solutions based on css background are not what I am looking for.

Comment: What is it you are trying to acheive? If you don't assign a height to the wrapper the image will just take up it's native size.

Comment: You'd better to set image as background.

Comment: @Paulie_D I add what I want to achieve in my question. I don't assign a height to the wrapper but a max-height and indeed the image takes up it's native size, you are right but I don't understand why. Do you have any resources to help me understand this part of css?

Comment: @3rdthemagical cannot use background images, images are not styling elements in my case but content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the image a background to a div or container like this

```
<div id='box'>
    <div id='image'></div>
</div>

html, body {
    width: 100;
    height: 100%;
}
#box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background: #eee;
}
#image {
    background-image: url(http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg);
    background-size: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

You see the image has a fixed height, the container can have a variable % based width or height.

Comment: Probably works but the image represent some meaningful content in the document. It has to be semantically part of the HTML. Background images are considered as styling elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the wrapper to enforce height. Instead, directly set the `max-height` for the `<img>` tag in your CSS. I've added a snippet below with a slider (I did not include the functionality for the slide pagination buttons):

```js
(function() {
  var sliderItemIdx = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    var allSliderItemEls = document.querySelectorAll('.slider > .slider-item');
    var activeSliderItemEls = document.querySelectorAll('.slider > .slider-item.active');

    // Update the current item index
    sliderItemIdx = (sliderItemIdx + 1) % allSliderItemEls.length;

    // Remove active class
    [].forEach.call(activeSliderItemEls, function(sliderItemEl) {
      sliderItemEl.classList.remove('active');
    });

    // Add active to current item
    allSliderItemEls[sliderItemIdx].classList.add('active');

  }, 2000);

})();
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

.slider {
  background: #a00;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slider-item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}

.slider-item.active {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.slider-item img { max-height: calc(50vh - 30px); }
.pagination { line-height: 30px; }
.pagination > .page { text-decoration: none; font-size: 2.5em; }
.pagination > .page::before { content: '\2022'; }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <figure class="slider-item active">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/memI0.png">
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider-item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/P59NF.png">
  </figure>
  <figure class="slider-item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg">
  </figure>
  <div class="pagination">
    <a class="page" href="#item-1" title="Item 1"></a>
    <a class="page" href="#item-2" title="Item 2"></a>
    <a class="page" href="#item-3" title="Item 3"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I am using `calc` to allow for the pagination to fit below it.

Comment: First solution works but not in my real world example. It is a picture slider with pagination bullets at the bottom of the slides, I want both the slides and the pagination bullets to never takes more than a certain height relative to the viewport height (hence the use of vh unit).
The second solution is not semantically correct. The image is content, not styling, therefore, it cannot be a background image.

Comment: You are definitely correct. Now that we know you are building a slider, a background image is not semantically correct. I'll update the answer

Comment: @AliaSpencer Updated. Let me know if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: I was not aware of the calc function. I can now use `max-height: calc(100vh - <number>px);` but that imply to know/compute the value `<number>` in advance. Thank you for your answer, it solves my real world problem but does not exactly answer my question.